# Tab.Navigator props is not shown

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native.
I want to access the **tab Bar Options**  property of the Tab Navigator tag but it is shown.
Does any know the how to solve this?

here is my code:

```
 import React from 'react';
 import {View, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, Text} from 'react-native';
 import {Na  vigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
 import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
 import HomeScreen from './app/screens/HomeScreen';
 import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

 const Stack = createStackNavigator();
 const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator  {/* HERE I Want to use the PROPS!!!!!!!   */} >
        <Tab.Screen />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

function HomeStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="HomeScreen"
      screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#841548'},
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        headerTitleStyle: {fontWeight: 'bold'},
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="HomeScreen"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{title: 'Home Page'}}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'},
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you wanna implement a custom TabBar, you can access props like below:

```
<Tab.Navigator tabBar={props => <CustomTabBar {...props} />}>
  {...}
</Tab.Navigator>
```